# Delay in LDO Output

Tags: power-supply, power, delay, ldo

I am using this [LDO](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l4995.pdf)

I want to know how to find the delay between my Input Voltage and Output Voltage.

Suppose my Input voltage to the IC is 12V and Output is 5V. How to find the delay between the time I provide the input voltage and the time I get the output voltage?

Comment: By simulation or measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to charge the sum of all the output capacitances subject to the maximum output current limit, also the internal control loop has to stabilize.

If your output capacitance is, say, 20uF then 800-900mA will charge it in maybe 100-200usec and if you observe Fig 25, the control loop should stabilize in a couple hundred microseconds, so I would guess that 1ms should be plenty of time for the output to be be in regulation following the application of adequate input voltage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how did you arrive at the value of 100-200usec for 20uF & 800-900mA? What is the formula you have used

Comment: T = C*\$\Delta V\$/I

Comment: Unable to read the formula.

Comment: Time = capacitance * change in voltage, divided by currrent.

Comment: Thank youu, And this formula applies to Output of switching regulators like Buck, Boost topologies also, right?

Comment: If the regulator can supply that current into a short-circuit, yes. If it's a foldback limiting type that needs to be taken into account.

Comment: Into a short-circuit? And what do you mean by foldback limiting?

Comment: The capacitor acts as a short circuit during startup. Foldback current limiting is a regulator characteristic or feature that reduces the maximum output current for low output voltage to protect the regulator in case of a prolonged short-circuit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. And one last question, you mentioned like, "If the regulator can supply that current into a short-circuit", at what conditions, the regulator cannot supply that current? Regulators do always provide current when input voltage is provided.

Comment: It depends on the regulator design, for example, it can't supply hardly any current for very low input voltage. To do a complete analysis would be very complex and would vary from unit-to-unit, hence I doubled or tripled the number.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The delay depends upon the size of the discrete capacitor on LDO output.

An LDO has a large power transistor connected between Vin and Vout, with large parasitics.

These parasitics insure ZERO DELAY for high frequency spikes.

=====================

however, regarding the effect of LARGE LOAD CAPACITORS ---- I was asked to explain the "plateauing" of such an LDO. I explained the required charge was so
large the on-chip power transistor was OVERHEATING during the milliSeconds required to reach even 40% or 50% of final voltage, and the LDO entered Self-Protect Mode, pausing to let the die cool down (some milliseconds), then continued to charge the external Cload to the final voltage.

So don't casually load a LDO with huge capacitors. A SwitchReg may be OK with such, but not an LDO.